# Use value before and after the decimal point in c++ float?

Tags: c++, floating-point

```
double f;
cin >> f;
cout << f << endl;
int n1 = f;
int diff = f - n1;
cout << diff <<  endl;
```

I want the number before and after the decimal point in separate int. (Take the example of double f = 101101.11001 I am getting diff as zero but not the numbers.) I have just started learning C++. Need some guidance.

Comment: When you convert to an integer the fractional part is thrown away so diff has to be 0.

Comment: Make `diff` a double. Or multiply by 10 thousand first if your numbers look like the example.

Comment: Oh ! I should have taken float diff instead of int diff. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Decimal is a radix. You mean 'decimal *point*'.

Answer (score 1):

> OP: I want the number before and after the decimal in separate `int`.

Avoid `int n1 = f;` as it does not have the range of `double`.  An `int` cannot encode a fraction without scaling.

Research `modf()` to break a `double` into whole number and fractional parts.

```
double modf(double value, double *iptr);
```

> The `modf` functions break the argument value into integral and fractional parts, each of which has the same type and sign as the argument. They store the integral part (in floating-point format) in the object pointed to by `iptr`.

```
#include <cmath>

double f;
cin >> f;
cout << f << endl;
double whole;
double frac = modf(f, &whole);

cout << whole <<  endl;
cout << frac <<  endl;
```

---

If code still want to go the `int` approach.  Read as a string and parse, noting the number of characters after the `'.'`. Then scale the fraction by that count so input `"123.00456"` becomes `123` and `456/100000`

Answer (score 0):

Stick to the decimal data type for operation result, you can use float or double, doesn't matter. The mistake on your code above is you're using int diff as result, remember that int data type convert everything to integers itself meanwhile you wanted it decimal.

```
double f;
cin >> f;
int n1 = f;
double diff = f - n1;
float diff2 = f - n1;
cout << "Using double : " << diff << endl
    << "Using float  : " << diff2 << endl;
```

Comment: Curious to  use `float` here.  With input like 123.999999999999, the `f - n1` difference will round to 1.0 when assigned to `diff`.  Best not to introduce another type here and stick with `double`.

Comment: Please add an explanation to this answer

Comment: explanation given.